# Gitlab clone over http fails to authenticate from external network

Tags: http, authentication, nginx, clone, gitlab

I have Gitlab 5.2 + Nginx installed on a local machine in my university. Clone over http works for machines that are within the internal network, but trying to clone from a machine on an external network results in an "fatal: Authentication failed" message, even though the exact same credentials are supplied. (I use the same credentials as the ones I use to log in to Gitlab via the web interface)

The Gitlab web interface is accessible from external networks. It is only the clone over http that fails (clone over ssh is not possible because port 22 is blocked)

Here are some lines from the relevant configuration files:

from config/gitlab.yml

```
host: mydomain
port: 80
https: false
```

Here are the relevant lines from the ngnix config file

```
server {
  listen *:80 default_server;         # In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name mydomain;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 2000; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 2000; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

Note: I have added this line to /etc/hosts: `127.0.0.1 mydomain` but it doesn't really help. (based on https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3483#issuecomment-15783597)

Any ideas on what the issue might be/how I might debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is fixed in 5.3, so try updating. See:

- https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/CHANGELOG#L41
- https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L151

Comment: Just to clarify - I don't use LDAP authentication. The weird thing is that git over http actually works from the internal network. It only fails when I try to do it from an external network.